# CAGradientLayer not changing the background color

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to create a gradient as a background color for my UIView. I wrote this code

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue,UIColor.yellow]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)


self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

but the view still the same set on the Interface Builde. If I add this line before the code

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

the background color changes to white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

try this code. It works for me swift 3

Comment: okay, glad it fixed your issue :)
Can you please upvote my answer as well ?

Comment: @cole - for future reference, when you post an answer, try to include the *why* - not just "here, this code works".

Comment: Okay, thanks for your feedback. Will keep in mind next time